# How can I change sendgrid account to another one?

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

I have a problem with sendgrid. Recently I created two accounts with the same email in sendgrid. But after a while I wrote to sendgrid support to delete one of them. They did it. And now, when I try to add sendgrid I have the next erorr:

```
An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create sendgrid:starter: Error Provisioning User - User status - banned
```

Support of sedngrid said me that my first account was banned but second is valid and I can use it.
The question is: How can I change sendgrid account in heroku? Or how can I set it up.
I was wondering if someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, the only one way to solve it is to write to Heroku support. I did it, but they still didn't solve it. I will write as they will find the solution!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? There's not even a way to create a support ticket on Heroku!

Comment: Finally, Heroku support team and SendGrid support team have solved my problem together. I've created a ticket on Heroku with that issue and Heroku support team connected with SendGrid support team. In the end my problem was solved! So there is only one way to solve it!